# Delta function from poles of Green's function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, greens-functions, dirac-delta-distributions, s-matrix-theory

In quantum mechanical scattering theory, we often use Green's functions which contain poles. For example, in Schroedinger quantum mechanics the free Green's function is given by

$$
G_0(\vec{p}) = \frac{1}{E-\frac{p^2}{2m}+i\epsilon}
$$

in momentum space where the infinitesimal constant $\epsilon >0$ has been introduced to take care of the pole at $E = \frac{p^2}{2m}$. The imaginary part of $G_0$ is then

$$
\text{Im}G_0 = -\frac{\epsilon}{(E-\frac{p^2}{2m})^2+\epsilon^2}
$$

and letting $\epsilon$ go to zero, we get (using the Sokhotski–Plemelj formula)

$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\text{Im}\,G_0=-\pi\delta\left(E-\frac{p^2}{2m}\right).
$$

The full Green's function is then given by the Dyson equation

$$
G = G_0 + G_0 VG_0 + G_0VG_0VG_0+\ldots
$$

with the scattering potential $V$. Looking at the second term in the Dyson equation, we see that the free Green's function appears twice giving rise to an expression proportional to $\frac{1}{(E-p^2/(2m)+i\epsilon)^2}$. I wonder what the imaginary part of this expression is. Phyiscally, there should still be some delta function because the physical particle fulfills the relation $E=\frac{p^2}{2m}$ even after elastic scattering but I don't see how the delta enters the game. So, how can I get a delta function from the fraction

$$
\frac{1}{(E-\frac{p^2}{2m}+i\epsilon)^2}?
$$

Comment: The assumption that the momentum does not get changed by the interaction is unjustified.

Answer (score 1):

The Green functions $G$ and $G_0$, as well as the scattering potential $V$ are operators. Therefore, if we choose to work in the momentum space, the string of operators, e.g. $G_0 V G_0$, have to be written as a convolution and all the dummy variables have to be integrated out. Doing this, you will never obtain a square of the free Green function as you claim. You shouldn't interpret Dyson equation a mere multiplication of functions.

Comment: In position space $G_0VG_0$ corresponds to convolution; in momentum space, to multiplication. This is a basic property of the Fourier transform: it maps convolutions to point-wise products and vice-versa.

Comment: It depends on the operator. Potentials are usually multiplicative in position space and convolutive in the momentum space.